# Hierarchical Structure Alogrithm

Tags: php, jquery, multidimensional-array

Hopefully I can get some help on this as I am not familiar with tree building algorithms.

This is my sample data:

```
record_id               parent_id
ITSM                    null    //<-- this is the parent
APP1                    ITSM
SERVER1                 APP1
SERVER2                 APP1
DATABASE1               SERVER2
```

I need to produce an alogirthm that will build an array where the output will be in the below form:

```
var data =
  { "items": [
          { "items": [
                  { "title": "SERVER1" },
                  { "items": [
                          { "title": "DATABASE1" }
                      ],
                      "title": "SERVER2"
                  }
              ],
              "title": "APP1"
          }
      ],
      "title": "ITSM"
  };
```

It will also need to account for other relationships that are not listen in the sample data, for example, if we had DATABASE2 being related to SERVER1 which it is not in the case however the possiblity is there.

this will result in the following tree diagram:

```
              ITSM
               |
        SERVER1  SERVER 2
                    |
                 DATABASE1
```

Answer (score 0):

for your provided json data php array staructure be

```
array(
       'items' => array(
             'items' => array(
                 'title' => 'SERVER1',

            ),
          //rest of your code

        ),
);
```

Comment: not sure if this is even an answer to my question. I'm working on trying to produce a result array based on the sample table I mentioned